# Flutter - How to prefill a form's data through a Popup Menu Button

Tags: flutter, forms, dart

I have an inkwell that when I tap, I receive all the data and it prefills into a form. I'm trying to implement the same functionality through a popup menu button but not sure how to access the variables needed. My itembuilder for the inkwell is this:

```
itemBuilder: ((context, index) => InkWell(
                                    onTap: () => Navigator.of(context)
                                        .pushNamed(EditSettings.routeName,
                                            arguments: accounts[index].id),
                                    child: ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
                                      value: accounts[index],
                                      key: ValueKey(accounts),
                                      child: const AccountView(),
                                    ),
```

I can easily get to the form with navigator, and I can make a provider that grabs the argument accounts, but not sure how to filter the index to prefill the form.

The PopupMenuButton and the PopupMenuItem code are as follows:

```
PopupMenuButton(
              onSelected: (AccountOptions selection) {
                setState(() {
                  if (selection == AccountOptions.passVisible) {
                    _passwordVisible = true;
                  } else if (selection == AccountOptions.passInvisible) {
                    _passwordVisible = false;
                  } else if (selection == AccountOptions.editAccount) {
                  //Not sure what to put here
                  }


 const PopupMenuItem(
                  value: AccountOptions.editAccount,
                  child: Text('Edit Account'),
                ),
```

The form has four fields, a name, url, password, and username. Any help would be appreciated!

I've made a provider, tried to make a loop but am unsure how to grab the needed info

Answer (score 0):

The fields can have default values.

`_controller = new TextEditingController(text: 'Initial value');`

Since you are using the provider You can wrap the fields around with consumer or selectors. You can update the value in the state. Which is not a good practice. But that will do.

Another way would be to use non constant variables and update them
inside the form widget initState. you can use some widget variable to store the value which you have received from the data source and then use these values as default values.